# How to block certain countries from accessing our website at Azure?

Tags: security, azure

Normally, we restrict access to our website from certain countries at the edge of our network.  We are about to deploy our application to Azure and need to block certain countries from accessing it.  This is due to U.S. Embargo policies...  What is the best way to block certain countries so we meet U.S. laws and regulations?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to build a simple proxy that attempts to filter on region. My teammate Ricardo Villalobos co-wrote an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198240.aspx) explaining how someone might do that with node.js, in Azure, filtering against the [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) geolocation database. It's probably not an exact fit, as it deals with media stream filtering, but you should be able to use the basic technique and proxy described, as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your suggestion!  We will be deploying an ASP.NET webapp to Azure, so we could implement an HTTP filter and use MaxMind.  I will need to do more research.

Comment: Will we have the ability to block countries in Azure Websites in the future? I'm trying to block a country and the web.config file is now greater than 250KB because of all the IP address ranges. I can't make it bigger because you can't change registry keys in Azure Websites, or can you?